# error mysqli could not be converted to string in E:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, mysqli

Este es un proyecto que ya funcionaba con "mysql_" ahora con "mysqli_" hice los ajustes que considere, pero arroja el error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string in E:\xampp\htdocs\

```
<?php include("config.php"); $nombre =
htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['nombre'])); $apell =
htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['apellidos'])); $login =
htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login'])); $pass1 =
trim($_POST['pass1']); $pass2 = trim($_POST['pass2']); $email =
htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])); $link =
mysqli_connect($datos[0],$datos[1],$datos[2],$datos[3])or
die(mysqli_error($link)); $query = sprintf($link, "SELECT login FROM
usuarios WHERE usuarios.login='%s'",
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$login)); $result =
mysqli_query($datos[3],$link,$query); if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
echo "usuario ya existente, por favor intentalo de nuevo."; } else { mysqli_free_result($result); if($pass1 != $pass2){ echo "Los
passwords deben coincidir, por favor intentalo de nuevo."; } else {
$pass1 = sha1(md5($pass1)); $query = sprintf($link,"INSERT INTO
usuarios (nombre, apellidos, login, password, email) VALUES
('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$nombre)
, mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$apell),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$login) ,
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$pass1),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$email)); $result =
mysqli_query($datos[3],$query,$link); if(mysqli_affected_rows()){ echo
"usuario introducido correctamente.<br>"; echo "<a
href='login.php'>Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n</a>"; } else { echo "Error
introduciendo el usuario"; } } } ?>
```

El error que aparece es este:

> error mysqli could not be converted to string in E:\xampp\htdocs\chat\regisuser.php on line 11

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda que colocaras en qué linea está el error.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] seria de gran ayuda que indentes el código para facilitar la lectura. También te recomiendo que pases por [ask]. Un saludo.